# Points to slashes with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have text file like this format:

```
...
SomeText.any_text/ch SomeText2.any_3/ch 5.6e-5
SomeText.any_text/ch something.else.point.separated/ch4 5.4e5
...
```

in line I have three elements: two - alpha-numerical-underscored-slashed strings and one - float number.

I need to replace points to slashes only at strings.

I have try to use sed with regular expression like this

```
sed 's/\([\w_]\+\)\(\.\)/\1\//g'
```

And don't have positive result.

Comment: y are u using `\(\)` and `\1`..

Comment: @Anirudha: (a) Please don't use SMS-ese on SO.  (b) POSIX `sed` (meaning portable `sed`) uses `\(...\)`; GNU `sed` is non-standard and doesn't use that notation unless you ask it to with `--posix`, but ... well, let's say that the point (one of the points) of having standards is to make it easy to move software around, and GNU `sed` being non-standard makes it harder on everyone.  (OTOH, POSIX `sed` does not recognize `\w` as a metacharacter sequence.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `sed` makes it so difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^ ]*$/\n&/;h;y/./\//;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Explanation:

- `s/[^ ]*$/\n&/` insert a newline before the last field
- `h` copy the pattern space (PS) to the hold space (HS)
- `y/./\//` translate all `.`'s to `/`'s in the PS
- `G` append a newline then HS to the PS
- `s/\n.*\n//` remove everything between the first and last newlines i.e. delete the old strings

This idiom can be used to simplify changing part of a line without the need to resorting to complicated regexp's

Answer (score 1):

Your elements look like fields. Therefore, my preferred method would be to use `awk`:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=2; i++) gsub(/\./, "/", $i) }1' file.txt
```

Results:

```
SomeText/any_text/ch SomeText2/any_3/ch 5.6e-5
SomeText/any_text/ch something/else/point/separated/ch4 5.4e5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in classic `sed` notation with a couple of loops, one to fix dots in the first field, and one to fix dots in the second field.

```
sed -e ':f1' -e 's/^\([^ .]*\)\./\1\//'                  -e 't f1' \
    -e ':f2' -e 's/^\([^ ][^ ]*\) \([^ .]*\)\./\1 \2\//' -e 't f2'
```

The `^` anchors are crucial to this working correctly.  Yes, you can write it all on one line in a single argument to `sed`; I prefer the clarity of separate arguments when the script is a complex as this.  A typical `sed` script is inscrutable enough without adding any extra obstacles to comprehension.

```
sed ':f1;s/^\([^ .]*\)\./\1\//;t f1;:f2;s/^\([^ ][^ ]*\) \([^ .]*\)\./\1 \2\//;t f2'
```

For your input sample (two lines), the output is:

```
SomeText/any_text/ch SomeText2/any_3/ch 5.6e-5
SomeText/any_text/ch something/else/point/separated/ch4 5.4e5
```

If you're using GNU `sed`, you might need to add `--posix` to the options, though it seemed to behave itself correctly (so it probably recognized that I wasn't using any non-POSIX notations and therefore stuck with POSIX).

Tested on Mac OS X 10.7.5 with BSD `sed` and GNU `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/\./,"",$1);;gsub(/\./,"",$2);print}' your_file
```